Does a the USB line for a ESP32-S3 require ESD protection?
I use an ESP32-S3-WROOM-1-N16R8 (Datasheet) together with a USB connector which allows me to flash it easily. But do I need some extra ESD protection for the USB? I added a USBLC6-2SC6 to the schematics this way, but is it really required or already required by the ESP32 module itself?

In the datasheet on page 84 it says:

8.2 Electrostatic Discharge (ESD)
• Human body model (HBM): ±2000 V
• Charged-device model (CDM): ±500 V

Does this apply to the GPIO pins?

Can you somehow rephrase the question? Obviously it does not need any protection to work, but also you don't mention what kind of level of protection you expect, need, or want?

I don't know what level of protection I need, because I am not that experienced. It is just a normal PCB with an ESP32-S3 module on it, so a relatively normal use case.

Required is a strong word. It will work without protection, however best practice would include it.
USB will have connecting and disconnecting making it a particularly prone area to possibly damaging surges when you touch the device.
If you are attaching and detaching whatever you have on the GPIO pins while in use I'd also recommend the TVS there too.
